# Asp.net mvc Html.Action render at wrong position

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

the code is

```
<div class="container" >
 @Html.Action("aaa","bbb");
</div>
```

the action output string "123",
What I want is

```
    <div class="container" >
123
    </div>
```

but actually the result is

```
123
<div class="container" >

</div>
```

the action result place in wrong position ,why and how resolve ,Thanks in advance

action code below

```
  public ActionResult Test(string custEmpId)
        {

            model.code = "123";


            return PartialView(model);
        }
```

Comment: Please put action code

Comment: Where partial view html content and model?
Please update question with true code.